# getting specific php variable out of a loop to jquery function parameter

Tags: php, jquery, loops

i have a auto suggest textbox witch generates li tags with a onclick event with a function but i have to pass a php variable to the function as parameter but i only want the variable value of the li the user clicked on and now i always get the last variable in the loop.
And i want the var test to be the value of $test = $row['t_product']; of the li the user clicks on

here is the code im using now:

```
    if(isset($_POST['search_term']) == true && empty($_POST['search_term']) == false){    
    $search_term = $_POST['search_term'];
     $customerid = $_SESSION['userdata']['t_customer_id'];

 $conn = connect();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Licenses WHERE customer_id = '$customerid' AND t_name LIKE '$search_term%'";
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

while(($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) != false){
$test = $row['t_product'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var test = <?php echo json_encode($test); ?>;
</script>
<?php
        echo '<li onclick="show(test)">', $row['t_name'], '</li>';
         }

}
```

i hope i explained my problem well and hope that some wane can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by passing the $test value as id to each li and in the js get it with

```
 $test = $row['t_product'];
    echo '<li onclick="show(this)" id="'.$test.'">', $row['t_name'], '</li>'

function show(id){
    alert($(id).attr("id"));}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe you should do :

```
while(($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) != false){
  $test = $row['t_product'];
?>
<?php
  echo '<li onclick="show("'.$test.'")">', $row['t_name'], '</li>';
}
```

or

```
if(isset($_POST['search_term']) == true && empty($_POST['search_term']) == false){ 
  $index = 0;
  $search_term = $_POST['search_term'];
  $customerid = $_SESSION['userdata']['t_customer_id'];

  $conn = connect();
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Licenses WHERE customer_id = '$customerid' AND t_name LIKE '$search_term%'";
  $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

  while(($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) != false){
    $test = $row['t_product'];
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var test<?php echo $index++ ?> = "<?php echo $test; ?>";
    </script>
<?php
    echo '<li onclick="show(test'.$index++.')">', $row['t_name'], '</li>';
  }
}
```

Edit: removed json_encode and replaced it with quotes

Comment: the first option you gave returns ReferenceError: json_encode is not defined show(json_encode($test)); in firebug thrying the second one now

Comment: second one olso returns not defined ex(test1 or test2 or test3)

Comment: Basically the issue is that you define the same variable more than once, write it directly or adding an index to the variable name prevent you to overwrite the value.

Comment: when i use show('.$test.') it returns the correct data but firebug says that ex(ICM) is not defined