# Get variable out of the loop

Tags: php

I have a query and I get the value of one row. For that I read the rows using a while loop and into the loop I save the value into a variable. Then I need to operate with this variable out of the loop but when I execute the code Apache show the follow error **`Undefined variable: distancia`**. I try to define the variable as global but it doesn't change its value. How can I use the variable outside the loop?
This is the code I have:

```
$re=$mysqli->query("SELECT Distancia FROM DESPLAZAMIENTO");
while($row2=$re->fetch_array()){
    $distancia=$row2["Distancia"];
}
$paga=$paga+(($distancia*0.24)*2);
```

Comment: can you echo $distancia inside the loop?

Comment: Try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564052/getting-specific-php-variable-out-of-a-loop-to-jquery-function-parameter

Comment: If I print the variable into the loop it's printing right. The while loop is for read the result of the row and save it into the variable `$distancia`

Comment: Please add a double quote to end of your Query.

Comment: try to put `$paga=$paga+(($distancia*0.24)*2);` inside the loop, it doesn't have much sense this way

Comment: @AD7six the warning is in the last line. In `$paga=$paga+(($distancia*0.24)*2);`

Comment: @gbestard if I put this into the variable I have the same problem because I need to use `$paga` in next lines.

Comment: It's not possible for the code to be entering the while loop _and_ be returning an undefined variable warning after that while statement. There's a logical discrepancy there. Add the full warning message and indicate which line of code in the question it's referring to (avoid assumptions - check).

Comment: @temerariomalaga te faltan unas dobles comillas despues de desplazamiento, y si necesitas sumar las distancias, la línea de paga deberia ir dentro del while

Comment: @gbestard I have the double quote in my script. It was an error pasting the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possibility for this error is **your query must have failed** .. because you are assigning the value `$row` to `$distancia` inside the `while` loop , so since the query failed , the control would not have been gone inside, but you are accessing the `$distancia` variable outside of the loop.

#### Enough rants.. how to tackle this problem ?

- Make sure your query is successful.
- Another way is check the rowCount , if it is zero , then don't do the below operation.

i.e.

```
$re=$mysqli->query("SELECT Distancia FROM DESPLAZAMIENTO");
$row_cnt = $re->num_rows;

while($row2=$re->fetch_array()){
    $distancia=$row2["Distancia"];
}
if($row_cnt>0)
{
 $paga=$paga+(($distancia*0.24)*2);
}
```

Comment: The query returns one row. It isn't problem of the query.

Comment: @temerariomalaga, so what's the _exact_ problem you are facing?

Comment: The probel is that I can't use the variable if is't out of the loop.

Comment: @temerariomalaga, Did you follow the approach I showed you in the answer ? If so, what happened ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I dont know wheather it is typo or not but you missed double quote at the of the query

```
$re=$mysqli->query("SELECT Distancia FROM DESPLAZAMIENTO");
```

And then try this code :

```
$re=$mysqli->query("SELECT Distancia FROM DESPLAZAMIENTO");
while($row2=$re->fetch_array()){
    $distancia=$row2["Distancia"];

    $paga=$paga+(($distancia*0.24)*2);
}
```

Comment: If I put that into the while loop then I can't to use `$paga` because it's undefined too.

Comment: You don't seem to want to admit the obvious @temerariomalaga - you are _not_ entering your while loop.

Comment: I enter to the loop. If I print `$distancia ` into the loop it's print right.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
$distancia = "";

$re = $mysqli_query("SELECT Distancia FROM DESPLAZAMIENTO", YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING);

while( $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($re) )
{
    $distancia = $row2["Distancia"];
}

$paga=$paga+(($distancia*0.24)*2);
```

Replace `YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING` for your string.

Comment: The conection isn't the problem. I define it in previous lines.

Comment: I know its not i was just making sure ;). the Pos is about defining the variable before while loop

Comment: I define the variable and it works but I will make some adjust for run it with other variables I have.

Comment: If i declare the variable outside the loop when I use the variable in the operation the value of $distancia is 0;

Comment: Are you sure it is in your database as integer? $paga=$paga+(($distancia*0.24)*2); this must all be int

Comment: `$distancia` is a float.

Comment: In the loop, try $distancia = $distancia +  $row2["Distancia"]

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else seemed to catch this

```
$distancia = 0;

$re=$mysqli->query("SELECT Distancia FROM DESPLAZAMIENTO");  // doublequote at end
while($row2=$re->fetch_array()){
    //$distancia=$row2["Distancia"];
    $distancia += $row2['Distancia'];   
}
$paga+=(($distancia*0.24)*2);
```

To me it seems you are not trying to get one record. So if this loop goes through distancia will always be the last record disancia. So I adjusted it to use a sum of those results.

Comment: If I do it `$distancia` is 0.

Comment: your query is returning no results ... or they are all 0's

Comment: the query return results. If I print it into the loop it print the result. The problem is if I declare the variable when I use it the value is the same that the value that I declare.

Comment: maybe you should update your question with a small db dump or something to show that you are getting results ... we are not psychics here.